# Who should own wordpress/drupal files on my webserver?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, file-permissions

I have a Centos server running apache, php, and pure-ftp.

I have 2 sites (domains) through apache, one of them wordpress and one of them drupal.  I uploaded them using my ftp account as user `"ftpuser"` and group `"ftpgroup"`.  Apache is running as user `"apache"` and php the same `(apache)`.

I have not changes the file permissions for anything, but I did realize that I needed to supply FTP credentials for both wordpress and drupal when downloading modules, which i didn't have to do when I had everything set to 777 permissions (a long time ago, before I knew about permissions)

What user and groups should the files have.  I know that directories should be 755 (or 775?) and files should be 644 (or 664?).  But what user/groups should they be under?

Comment: I think this one belongs to ServerFault not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your case, the user should be "apache", but if You couldn't make chown on files, probably, You will have to put 777 on some directories, as sites/default/files/ .